# What's the efficient way to change the order of documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my schema, there is a field named `order`. Which is simply a counter that increments in each insert. And I fetch the data sorted by the `order` field. So the documents would look like this

```
{ name: 'A', order: 1 }
{ name: 'B', order: 2 }
{ name: 'C', order: 3 }
```

Now I want to, for instance, put C above A. Which means docs should look like this

```
{ name: 'C', order: 1 }
{ name: 'A', order: 2 }
{ name: 'B', order: 3 }
```

Should I update `order` field in all documents one by one? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Ouch!  You'll need to update `order` for all docs whose `order` is equal to, or greater than, the smaller of the moved `order` old/new `order`, but whose `order` is less than the larger of the old/new `order`.  This could be done with one aggregation pipeline, or maybe one `updateMany`, but it's potentially a lot of doc rewriting.  Is there a more efficient data/doc model for your purpose?

Comment: Thanks. I myself am wondering if there's a more efficient model for user made ordering. A user needs to change the order of rows if they intend to, i.e with drag and drop. I don't think there's a better modeling than using an order field. Do you know any?

Comment: Using an order column seems sensible to me in your scenario. In addition, you may want to set your values in order column with some "buffer". In your example, you may want to initialize the orders to be 10, 20, 30. So when you change your ordering in your example, you can simply set C to be 5(or any value lower than A's 10) to avoid updating the whole collections. i.e. the final version would be C: 5, A: 10, B: 20